# CDN links in php include files

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap-4, cdn

I am working a site project with Bootstrap 4.4.1. I use the CDN links to place them right before closing the `</body>`. In order to avoid lots of coding in all pages, I want to use a php include file which contains all the scripts below/ This file I named "js-remote.php". This is inside a folder called "js".

I inserted the code on every content page (I am doing all php pages) and the path is:

`<?php include '../js/js-remote.php'>`

But doesn't work. I have navigation bar also as included file, the menu is shown but the dropdowns don't work properly. Even when I paste the full scripts codes of the CDN (without using any php include) don't work either.

ONLY works when I don't use the include files, just when pasting the complete code as a regular html file.Get below the code I wanna use in a php include file. Observations, please.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

But instead of pasting the whole scripts I just want to put one single line:

```
<?php include '../js/js-remote.php' ?>
</body>
<--! Could it work?-->
```

Where "js-remote.php" is a page which contains all the cdn scripts above and more coming in the future.

Sorry for the redundance but it's necessary. The "js-remote.php" file contains:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Can you show us the `js-remote.php` file as well?

Comment: Do you see the included code when you inspect the page source in a browser?

Comment: Yes! @beltouche And I saw that the the cdn links were like duplicated. So, I deleted all extra html from the include files and suprisingly, now it's working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see errors in the way the code is written here that would break the functionality if they're in the actual document.
The include should be written

```
<?php include '../js/js-remote.php'; ?>
```

In your post you left out the semicolon and `?>` in the first case and the final quote and semicolon in the second.

Comment: Sorry, actually I used the colon (') at the end. About the semicolon (;) I read that for php 7 is not necessary if the code is in just one only line, but anyway I tried with and without semicolon and still doesn't work. The path is correct. The code hints helped me to set the right path (../)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you need to place the scripts near the end of the document.

According to the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/#js):

> Many of our components require the use of JavaScript to function.
>   Specifically, they require jQuery, Popper.js, and our own JavaScript
>   plugins. Place the following s near the end of your pages,
>   right before the closing  tag, to enable them. jQuery must come
>   first, then Popper.js, and then our JavaScript plugins.